# How does makeLog instruction function works in Ethereum virtual machine

Tags: ethereum, opcode, go-ethereum, evm

The following code snippet is a constituent piece of the [instructions.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/instructions.go) file in geth.

```
// make log instruction function
func makeLog(size int) executionFunc {
    return func(pc *uint64, interpreter *EVMInterpreter, scope *ScopeContext) ([]byte, error) {
        if interpreter.readOnly {
            return nil, ErrWriteProtection
        }
        topics := make([]common.Hash, size)
        stack := scope.Stack
        mStart, mSize := stack.pop(), stack.pop()
        for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
            addr := stack.pop()
            topics[i] = addr.Bytes32()
        }

        d := scope.Memory.GetCopy(int64(mStart.Uint64()), int64(mSize.Uint64()))
        interpreter.evm.StateDB.AddLog(&types.Log{
            Address: scope.Contract.Address(),
            Topics:  topics,
            Data:    d,
            // This is a non-consensus field, but assigned here because
            // core/state doesn't know the current block number.
            BlockNumber: interpreter.evm.Context.BlockNumber.Uint64(),
        })

        return nil, nil
    }
}
```

The question is, how does log0 ,log1,Log2 etc opcode works and what is their use in Ethereum virtual machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LOG<n>` opcodes are used for emitting event logs.

The `<n>` value depends on the number of indexed and non-indexed topics of the event. Since the `<n>` value is limited (currently at 4), there's also a limit of max indexed topics per each event definition (currently 3, so it's possible to process unindexed topics of the same event as well).

Example in Solidity:

```
event MyEmptyEvent();
event MyEvent(bool indexed, bool indexed, bool, bool);

function foo() external {
    // Produces the `LOG0` opcode as there are no topics
    emit MyEmptyEvent();

    // Produces the `LOG3` opcode
    // as the 2 indexed topics are stored separately
    // but the unindexed topics are stored as 1 topic with concatenated value
    emit MyEvent(true, true, true, true);
}
```

After a transaction is included in a mined block, the produced event logs are broadcasted along with other state changes (e.g. storage values and address balances).

There's a great [article](https://medium.com/mycrypto/understanding-event-logs-on-the-ethereum-blockchain-f4ae7ba50378) describing the details in more depth.